# Entity Framework Core 2.2 orderby evaluated locally

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have this semi-complex query that counts the most voted user post of the last 7 days:

```
var fromDate = dateTimeService.Now.Add(-interval);
var votedPosts =
    from vote in dbContext.Votes
    join post in dbContext.Posts on vote.PostId equals post.PostId
    group new {vote.Sign, post.PostId} by post.PostId
    into postVotes
    select new {
        PostId = postVotes.Key,
        TotalRating = postVotes.Sum(pv => pv.Sign)
    };

var bestPost = (
    from post in dbContext.Posts
    join votedPost in votedPosts on post.PostId equals votedPost.PostId
    join room in dbContext.Rooms on post.RoomId equals room.RoomId
    join game in dbContext.Modules on room.ModuleId equals game.ModuleId
    where room.RoomAccess == RoomAccessType.Open && post.CreateDate > fromDate
    orderby votedPost.TotalRating descending,
        post.CreateDate descending
    select new BestPost
    {
        UserId = post.UserId,
        ModuleId = game.ModuleId,
        ModuleTitle = game.Title,
        PostId = post.PostId,
        PostText = post.Text,
        PostCommentary = post.Commentary,
        PostCreateDate = post.CreateDate,
        TotalRating = bestPost.TotalRating
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

What I try to do here is to group user votes by `PostId`, sum the evaluations of their votes by field `Sign` (can be -1, 0 or 1), then join it with some additional data like game Id/Title and post texts, filter non-public or too old posts, then order it by rank and then by create date, then map it onto DTO and return the very first result if present.

All the fields here are simple basic types: the `Vote.Sign` is `int`, `Post.CreateDate` is `DateTime`, all the `*Id` are `Guid` and `Text/Title/Commentary` are `string`.

I get the warning:

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>   The LINQ expression 'orderby [bestPost].TotalRating desc' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>   warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>   The LINQ expression 'FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

If I remove the sort by `TotalRating` and only leave the `CreateDate` sorting, it works fine, creates proper `LIMIT` request. But with `TotalRating` the query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    t."PostId", t."TotalRating", post."CreateDate" AS "PostCreateDate", 
    post."UserId", game."ModuleId", game."Title" AS "ModuleTitle", 
    post."PostId" AS "PostId0", post."Text" AS "PostText", 
    post."Commentary" AS "PostCommentary"
FROM
    "Posts" AS post
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         post0."PostId", SUM(vote."Sign")::INT AS "TotalRating"
     FROM 
         "Votes" AS vote
     INNER JOIN 
         "Posts" AS post0 ON vote."PostId" = post0."PostId"
     GROUP BY 
         post0."PostId") AS t ON post."PostId" = t."PostId"
INNER JOIN 
    "Rooms" AS room ON post."RoomId" = room."RoomId"
INNER JOIN 
    "Modules" AS game ON room."ModuleId" = game."ModuleId"
WHERE 
    (room."RoomAccess" = 0) AND (post."CreateDate" > @__fromDate_0)
```

And it looks pretty bad to be calculated in dotnet runtime.

I tried to wrap the result in another `select from`, but it didn't help. I also cannot do the group by on all the columns because then I won't be able to aggregate things like `ModuleId` because EF Core 2.2 does not support the `group.FirstOrDefault` things and PostgreSQL does not support `max(uuid)` (otherwise I could use `group.Max(g => g.ModuleId)`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. What you are hitting is current EF Core query translation defect. EF Core really brings me back in the days when we were trying different SQL constructs in order to control query execution plan. Same happens with EF Core. If you post the involved model classes, I can try finding equivalent translatable construct if any.

Comment: I am confused by the `TotalRating = bestPost.TotalRating` part.

Comment: What if you don't include `post.PostId` in the `votedPosts` group and just do `Sum` on the `postVotes`?

Comment: In fact, why even bother joining on `dbContext.Posts` in the `votedPosts` query? `var votedPosts =
        from vote in dbContext.Votes
        group vote.Sign by vote.PostId into voteSigng
        select new {
            PostId = voteSigng.Key,
            TotalRating = voteSigng.Sum()
        };`

Comment: BTW, my default response if that I don't think EF Core is ready for enterprise use, but I am not sure EF could do better in this case; the default response of most is why are you using `join` instead of navigation properties with EF?

Comment: @NetMage i do not use navigation properties because in current state of EFCore it is impossible to use navigation properties with aggregation functions in groups.

Comment: @NetMage I'm okay with something not ready for the enterprise, I use it in my petproject and this query is all covered with caches and stuff. I asked the question on github issues and got a response that this is a known issue, so - keep waiting for the 3.0 or EF6.3.

Comment: @NetMage and for your question about joining on dbContext.Posts - that makes total sense, I must have been to worried with the sorting thing to miss it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HenkHolterman what exactly is the issue with it?

Comment: @VladislavQulin there is no definition for `bestPost` in your code.

Comment: oh, sorry, it has to be `votedPost.TotalRating`, my fault

Comment: "my fault" - during posting? That puts the whole question in doubt. Always post (copy/paste) the exact code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I doubt it puts the whole question in doubt, but you do you.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you combine the gist of `votedPosts` into the query so you don't duplicate the `join` on `posts`?

```
var bestPost = (
    from post in dbContext.Posts
    join vote in dbContext.Votes on post.PostId equals vote.PostId into votej
    let voteTotalRating = votej.Sum(pv => pv.Sign)
    join room in dbContext.Rooms on post.RoomId equals room.RoomId
    join game in dbContext.Modules on room.ModuleId equals game.ModuleId
    where room.RoomAccess == RoomAccessType.Open && post.CreateDate > fromDate
    orderby voteTotalRating descending,
        post.CreateDate descending
    select new BestPost {
        UserId = post.UserId,
        ModuleId = game.ModuleId,
        ModuleTitle = game.Title,
        PostId = post.PostId,
        PostText = post.Text,
        PostCommentary = post.Commentary,
        PostCreateDate = post.CreateDate,
        TotalRating = voteTotalRating
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I faced the same problems, but even `Sum` was not translated to SQL properly. When I wrap the voteTotalRating into `group by` statement, I faced the very same issue I had before.

Comment: @VladislavQulin I am not following - what `group by` do you need for that? The group join should do all the grouping. Can you update your question? And what LINQ to SQL provider (SQL Engine) are you using?

Comment: first I followed the suggested code, EF was not able to translate `let` part and everything after that. Then I worked with your suggestion that I don't actually need to join the posts with votes to get the proper sum in the grouping, so I simplified the query from the question and faced the same issue I had. I use Npgsql provider for Postgre and use pg 10 as a DB.